# Adding a handler for the first button only

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a div on a page and it contains some buttons with the same class but without id. I'd like to be able to add a handler for it but only for the first button:

```
  $(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class", function() {
    alert("yes");
  });
```

The code adds a handler to all the buttons with in my_div with the certain class. How do I do the same thing only for the first button?

**UPDATE**:
I remove and add the buttons dynamically on the page. **Before** deleting this code works well, meaning it works only for the first button, not for any other buttons and this is what I want:

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class:eq(0)", function() {
  alert("yes");
 });
```

However, **after** removing and **adding** the first button again dynamically it doesn't work anymore but this one below does, although it works for **all** the buttons and this is NOT what I want:

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class", function() {
  alert("yes");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class:first-child", function() {
    alert("yes");
});
```

A working [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/6c4ZG/)

EDIT:

Updated [<kbd>FIDDLE</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/6c4ZG/2/) has the dynamically loaded element's usecase

Comment: but when I remove and then add this button dynamically, it doesn't work anymore. I wonder why.

Comment: Does it have the class name? Also, make sure the first-child is indeed that (may be you are adding it to the end. ) - if you are appending to the end, the second button is now the first button in the dom

Comment: in fact, ":first-child" doesn't work at all, only :eq(0) does and only for the first time (before deleting).

Comment: Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6c4ZG/2/ It should work just fine.

Comment: The thing is, by doing event delegating, `$(document).on(..)` you are accomodating the usecase where dynamic element are applied the listener.

Comment: thanks, the issue is about another thing. could you tell me how I can add a condition that this element doesn't have "display:none"? In other words, the first element in "my_div" with the class ".some_class" which doesn't have style  "display:none"?

Comment: just use the `:visible` selector (Alternate fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6c4ZG/3/)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery has a First-Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) which works pretty much exactly like the CSS3 counterpart which you can use. This will select the first instance of "`.some_class`" located within `#my_div`.

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class:first-child", function() {
    alert("yes");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `eq` selector which takes the index:

```
$(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class:eq(0)", function() {
    alert("yes");
});
```

There are also:

> `gt`: selects multiple greater than given index.
>
> `lt`: selects multiple lesser than given index.

**UPDATE**:

```
$(document).delegate("click", "#my_div .some_class:eq(0)", function() {
    alert("yes");
});
```

**Checking display:**

```
if($("selector").is(":hidden")) {
  //
}
```

> There is also:
>
> :visible, to check if the element is shown

**Attach to the first visible element**

```
$(document).delegate("click", "#my_div .some_class:visible:eq(0)", function() {
   alert('yes');
}
```

Comment: thanks, the issue is about another thing. could you tell me how I can add a condition that this element doesn't have "display:none"? In other words, the first element in "my_div" with the class ".some_class" which doesn't have style "display:none"?

Comment: but how do I apply it to `$(document).delegate("click", "#my_div .some_class:eq(0)", function() {`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique ID for the specific button you want to have the handler and use that to distinguish your button.

If you use a class to put handlers, all elements with that class will have the onclick handler (as long as it fits your query which is "#my_div .some_class")

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :first-child yet?

try,

```
  $(document).on("click", "#my_div .some_class:first-child", function() {
    alert("yes");
  });
```

But first, please check in your console if you can find that first child using this selector or not ?

```
  $("#my_div .some_class:first-child")
```